# Python MYSQL INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE incremented value

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to write Python code to insert a new row or if the primary key exists, then update 2 columns with new values which are calculated from variables.

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='admin', password='admin', host='127.0.0.1',     database='cr_database')
cur = cnx.cursor()

country_string = 'Canada'
number_string = '1234567890'
now_datetime = datetime.now()
attr1_integer = 1
attr2_integer = 10

cur.execute("INSERT INTO cr_table(cr_string, cr_date, cr_country_string, cr_attr1, cr_attr2) VALUES (%s %s %s %s %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE cr_attr1 = cr_attr1 + 1, cr_attr2 = cr_attr2 + VALUES(%s)",(number_string, datetime.now('%Y-%m-%d'), country_string , attr1_integer, attr2_integer, attr2_integer) )
```

but I get the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
the right syntax to use near '1 10) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cr_attr1 = cr_attr1 + 1, cr_attr2 = ' at line 1
```

The same query works perfectly in MySQL editor (after stripping out the Python code)
What am I doing wrong in my Python code?

Comment: Can you use `%s` placeholders for column names?

Comment: How do you suggest I use the %s placeholder for the column name? If I move the column name outside, the query I get a Python 'unresolved reference' error

Comment: I'm saying you are, which is questionable, as that might render it as a string, not a column name.

Comment: I edited the code above. No %s placeholders for column names now. cr_attr1 and cr_attr2 are column names and attr1_integer and attr2_integer are the python values being used to assign to the columns.

Comment: Don't you need a comma between each %s in the values part?

Comment: D-oh! I do! *facepalm*. Thank you!